# Links Image in "Catalog" Page to Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, theme-development, permalinks, images

I have a site with ["catalog" page](http://nusamebel.com/katalog/). It lists all of featured image, grabbed from all posts.

Unfortunately, the images in this "catalog" page aren't clickable. I wonder how to make each image clickable, and bring the visitor to the appropriate post.

This is the code of the "catalog" page:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: katalog
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="wpagen-konten">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="boxer"><?php virtarich_breadcrumbs(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><button class="btn pull-right" name=print value="Print Katalog" onClick="window.print()">Print Katalog <i class="icon-print"></i></button></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div class="row"><?php do_action( 'virtarich_katalog' ); ?>   </div>
<?php endwhile; ?><?php else : ?>
<div class="post"><h2>Not Found</h2>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</div>
<?php endif; ?>
           </div>
        <div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any helps will be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

-Studente-

> Update #1:
>   @DavidLee and @Ian

Thanks very much for your help. Uhm, I confuse about text formatting in the comments section. So, I paste the code here.

I think the code you mean is this:

```
function virtarich_katalog_function() {
        global $post;
        $vtr_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10000');
        while ($vtr_query->have_posts()) : $vtr_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-md-3 ikibro">
            <div class="wpagen-produk">
            <div class="katalog-gambar-center">
            <div class="katalog-gambar"><?php virtarich_thumb_normal() ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="katalog-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div class="katalog-harga">Rp <?php virtarich_harga(); ?><span class="coret"><?php virtarich_harga_coret(); ?></span></div>
            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "kode", $single = true) != ""){ ?> 
                Kode : <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "kode", $single = true);
                 } ?>
                 <br/>

            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "habis", $single = true)){ ?>
                <div class="habis senter">habis</div>
            <?php } else if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "stok", $single = true) != ""){  ?>
                Stok : <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "stok", $single = true);?>
            <?php } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
```

If I don't wrong, I think that's the code of `do_action( 'virtarich_katalog' );`

Please CMIIW,

> Update #2 the `functions.php` file

```
<?php
define('VTR_TEMPLATE_DIR_URI', get_template_directory_uri());
define('VTR_TEMPLATE_DIR', get_template_directory());
define('OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/admin/' );
require ( VTR_TEMPLATE_DIR . '/includes/admin/options-framework.php' );
require ( VTR_TEMPLATE_DIR . '/includes/core/core-function.php' );
require ( VTR_TEMPLATE_DIR . '/includes/stores/vtr-store.php' );
require ( VTR_TEMPLATE_DIR . '/includes/vtr-style.php' );

//Filter Halaman Search
function vtr_search_filter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('post'));
    }
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','vtr_search_filter');

//Css Revoslider
function revocss() {?>
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/settings.css" media="screen" />
<?php } 
 } add_action('wp_footer', 'revocss');?>
<?php
```

Many thanks.

Comment: can you show the code for this action `do_action( 'virtarich_katalog' );` it might be in `functions.php`, there is where the catalog is being made.

Comment: What code displays the featured image? Is it from the `virtarich_katalog` action as David mentioned above?

Comment: @DavidLee

I've edited the question above to add more code. I hope I put the right code you mean.


**Ian** Thanks matte. I really feel thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `virtarich_katalog_function` wrap the thumbnail with an `<a>` link tag like this:

```
function virtarich_katalog_function() {
        global $post;
        $vtr_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10000');
        while ($vtr_query->have_posts()) : $vtr_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-md-3 ikibro">
            <div class="wpagen-produk">
            <div class="katalog-gambar-center">
                <div class="katalog-gambar"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php virtarich_thumb_normal() ?></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="katalog-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div class="katalog-harga">Rp <?php virtarich_harga(); ?><span class="coret"><?php virtarich_harga_coret(); ?></span></div>
            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "kode", $single = true) != ""){ ?> 
                Kode : <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "kode", $single = true);
                 } ?>
                 <br/>

            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "habis", $single = true)){ ?>
                <div class="habis senter">habis</div>
            <?php } else if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "stok", $single = true) != ""){  ?>
                Stok : <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "stok", $single = true);?>
            <?php } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
```

to be more clear this is the line:

```
<div class="katalog-gambar"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php virtarich_thumb_normal() ?></a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidLee
<br>
You've helped me much. I know its a "small things" for you, but its a "big things" for me.


Btw, if you don't mind.. It drives me to another related question. Is it possible to make the "catalog page" just shows 40 photos each page?


I mean, is it possible to add such "Navigation" button? The `2, 3, Next, Last` like that?


Once again, thank you.

Comment: The pagination is going to be something complex. Read about please, and that would be another question after you have tried something.

Comment: I've took a look for the pagination. It's really complex for me. I've also found some threads in stackexchange about pagination with particular case. Of course its different with mine. I think that's all for now. Many thanks.